# Validationsummary not showing onclick of button

Tags: asp.net, validationsummary

I am using ASP.NET 1.1 and I'm having problems with my validationsummary and validationcontrols working. On button click, required field validations, etc are not fired. How do I fix this?

**Here's the code:**

```
<asp:ValidationSummary id="EsppDataInputValidationSummary" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" HeaderText="Please Correct the following error(s):" DisplayMode="List" ShowSummary="True"></asp:ValidationSummary></TD>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="Validator1" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial"
ControlToValidate="txtPrice" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter the Price"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:textbox onblur="return ValidateLength(this)" style="Z-INDEX: 0; TEXT-ALIGN: right" id="txtPurchasePrice" onkeypress="return IsValidChar(event);" onkeyup="return ValidateLength(this)" runat="server" Width="160px" MaxLength="10"></asp:textbox>

<asp:button id="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"></asp:button>"
```

Comment: There could be several explanations to this, we would need to see your code...

Comment: I meant all your relevant code... In aspx or codebehind as well.

Comment: please see updated above

Comment: Well if that's all you got, then a first problem is that you set `ControlToValidate` to "txtPrice" , while your TextBox's id is "txtPurchasePrice". Also, what are you doing in your codebehind ?  Are you testing the Page.IsValid property before doing anything ?

Comment: oh right..typo on my part. Aside from that? Its still not working..

Comment: cfr my answer below... Tentative of answer actually, but this is a classic mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be you're not testing the `Page.IsValid` property in you codebehind, but as you don't show it I couldn't be sure. You need to test it before doing anything, else your form will be submitted and you'll never get to actually see your validation summary...

So, in your `onClick` event handler, where you do all your stuff for now I presume :

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
//do the actions you wish here
}
```

Comment: another thing is, the button should only fire up 'Validator1' and not all validations in the page.

Comment: That's another problem. It's been a long time since I haven't done any 1.1, but I don't think this is possible in this version of the Framework, hence the introduction of ValidationGroups in further releases of the Framework. Have you tried with my code up here to see if you could already get you validation summary to show ?